# Search a datamodel with multiple section in collectionview

Tags: swift, search, keyword, collectionview, sections

I have the API response as given below:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "List Loaded Successfully.",
  "data": [
    {
      "movie_category": "Comedy",
      "movie_category_code": "comedy",
      "movie_list": [
        {
          "name": "Dhamaal",
          "description": "Four lazy slacker conmen buddies who are jobless, homeless and broke learn about the secret of a hidden treasure from a dying thief and later embark on a race against time to find the mobster's buried treasure and claim it while being pursued by a determined police inspector who is hellbent to get the treasure all by himself.",
          "release_year": "2007-09-07 07:00:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/dhamaal.jpg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/dhamaal.jpg",
          "ratings": "3.7",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "18.99418207785123",
              "longitude": "72.82443855189815"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "19.065931910428006",
              "longitude": "73.00118649905338"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "19.031441299550934",
              "longitude": "72.88098383204391"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bhagam Bhag",
          "description": "Champak, the owner of a theatre group, travels to London to organise a show along with Bunty and Bablya, two of his group members. They soon find themselves embroiled in a murder they did not commit.",
          "release_year": "2006-12-22 08:00:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/bhagam_bhag.jpg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/bhagam_bhag.jpg",
          "ratings": "3.3",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Hulchul",
          "description": "Anjali and Jai belong to two feuding families and pretend to be in love only to seek revenge. However, their plan goes awry when they really fall in love and decide to bring their families together.",
          "release_year": "2004-11-26 07:30:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/hulchul.jpg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/hulchul.jpg",
          "ratings": "4",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "18.99418207785123",
              "longitude": "72.82443855189815"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "movie_category": "Action",
      "movie_category_code": "action",
      "movie_list": [
        {
          "name": "Don",
          "description": "Vijay, a lookalike of criminal kingpin Don, is hired by DCP D'Silva in order to find Don's secrets. But after D'Silva dies, Vijay struggles to reveal his real identity.",
          "release_year": "2006-10-20 07:00:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/don.jpg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/don.jpg",
          "ratings": "4.1",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "18.99418207785123",
              "longitude": "72.82443855189815"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "19.065931910428006",
              "longitude": "73.00118649905338"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "19.031441299550934",
              "longitude": "72.88098383204391"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Bang Bang!",
          "description": "Harleen leads a boring life with her grandmother and works as a bank receptionist. However, her life takes a sudden turn after she falls in love with Rajveer, a thief.",
          "release_year": "2014-10-02 08:00:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/bang-bang.jpeg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/bang-bang.jpeg",
          "ratings": "3.1",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "Dhoom 2",
          "description": "Mr A, a fearless thief, steals valuable artefacts and teams up with the girl he is attracted to but cannot trust. Close on their heels are three police officers trying to apprehend them.",
          "release_year": "2006-11-24 07:30:00",
          "movie_banner": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/dhoom_2.jpg",
          "movie_icon": "http:\/\/apis.dev.ganniti.com\/assets\/images\/dhoom_2.jpg",
          "ratings": "4.3",
          "theatre_locations": [
            {
              "latitude": "19.099441290747407",
              "longitude": "72.91631061735934"
            },
            {
              "latitude": "18.99418207785123",
              "longitude": "72.82443855189815"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The model class for it is as given below:

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - MovieModel
struct MovieModel: Codable,Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: MovieModel, rhs: MovieModel) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    let success: Bool
    let message: String
    var data: [Datum]
}

// MARK: - Datum
struct Datum: Codable,Equatable {
    
    static func == (lhs: Datum, rhs: Datum) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    let movieCategory, movieCategoryCode: String
    let movieList: [MovieList]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case movieCategory = "movie_category"
        case movieCategoryCode = "movie_category_code"
        case movieList = "movie_list"
    }
}

// MARK: - MovieList
struct MovieList: Codable,Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: MovieList, rhs: MovieList) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    let name, movieListDescription, releaseYear: String?
    let movieBanner, movieIcon: String?
    let ratings: String?
    let theatreLocations: [TheatreLocation]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case movieListDescription = "description"
        case releaseYear = "release_year"
        case movieBanner = "movie_banner"
        case movieIcon = "movie_icon"
        case ratings
        case theatreLocations = "theatre_locations"
    }
}

// MARK: - TheatreLocation
struct TheatreLocation: Codable {
    let latitude, longitude: String?
}
```

This data from the API will be shown with multiple sections and multiple items inside.
The collection view datasource and delegate is as follows:

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return (self.moviemodel?.data.count)!
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return (self.moviemodel?.data[section].movieList.count)!
        default:
            return (self.moviemodel?.data[section].movieList.count)!
        }
        
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
        
        let cell = alllistcollview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MovielistCell
 return cell
    }
```

Now,there is a search textfield which will search for any keyword and filter the result to be shown in collectionview.

The search button function is as given below:

```
  var filteredShopsA = searchDataModel?.data.filter({ item in
            print("item is ",item)
       $0.matchAddress(keyword)
              return false
           })
 moviemodel?.data = filteredShopsA!
        
  self.alllistcollview.reloadData()
```

extension  MovieList  {

```
func matchAddress(_ string: String?) -> Bool {
    guard let string = string else { return true }
    guard let name = name else { return true }
    guard let desc =  movieListDescription else { return true }
    guard let year = releaseYear else { return true }
   // guard let rating = ratings else { return true }
    return (name.contains(string) || desc.contains(string) || year.contains(string))
}
```

}

The filter function is what i am not getting the logic correct to showcase the values on the collection view.How to search based on any text in this multiple sections of the collection view?

Comment: Does your filter call really compile? You are using both a named variable `item` and `$0` at the same time.

Comment: yeah thats what got really confused with the call.The Datum is there and it has search based on movielist array and also it has reload the collectionview.

Comment: item gives the datum.i need to search based on movielist which is inside datum.